# Django form inheritance with Crispy Forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I am trying to handle a form in Django in a more DRY way.  I am using Django Crispy Forms to lay out and render the forms.

I have a model:

```
class Txn(models.Model): 
    transaction_date = models.DateField()
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    arrived = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    used = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    sent= models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    adjust = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

For each of the 4 number fields (arrived, used, sent, adjust), I have a form that exposes just one of those fields.  (BTW, this is based on a model that was inherited from another project - I know there are better ways to structure this, but I have to use this structure).  So, I created 4 forms that look very similar:

```
class TxnUseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Txn
        fields = ('transaction_date', 'reference', 'used') 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TxnUseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Layout definition for the form
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                Column(Field('reference', autocomplete="off", autofocus="autofocus"), css_class='form-group col-sm-4 mb-0 pb-0'),
                Column(Field('transaction_date'), css_class='form-group col-sm-4 mb-0 pb-0'),
                Column(Field('used', step='1'), css_class='form-group col-sm-4 mb-0 pb-0')
            )
        )

    # Validation for amount used - must be a positive number
    def clean_used(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['used']
        if data is None or data == "":
            data=0
        if data <=0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Must be a positive number.")
        return data
```

The other 3 forms are called TxnArrivedForm, TxnAdjustForm, and TxnSentForm and are exactly the same as the TxnUsedForm - the only difference in the forms is the number field that is exposed.  I am trying to subclass the form and use inheritance to reduce code.  I have tried the following:

```
class TxnBaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Txn
        fields = ('transaction_date', 'reference')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TxnBaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Layout definition for the form
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                Column(Field('transaction_date'), css_class='form-group col-sm-4 mb-0 pb-0'),
                Column(Field('reference',  autocomplete="off", autofocus="autofocus"), css_class='form-group col-sm-4 mb-0 pb-0'),
            )
        )

class TxnUseForm(TxnBaseForm):
    class Meta(TxnBaseForm.Meta):
        fields = TxnBaseForm.Meta.fields + ('used',)
       
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TxnUseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper.layout.append =  Column(Field('used',step='1'), css_class='form-group col-sm-4 mb-0 pb-0')
        self.fields['used'].label = "Qty. Used"

    # Validation for amount used - must be a positive number
    def clean_used(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['used']
        if data is None:
            data=0
        if data <=0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Must be a positive number.")
        return data
```

The transaction date and reference fields show up, but the used field does not get rendered at all.  What am I doing wrong or missing?

Followup: Is there an easy way to handle the validation for that field in the base form since we do not know the name of the field yet?

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your code.

`self.helper.layout.append =  Column(Field('used',step='1'), css_class='form-group col-sm-4 mb-0 pb-0')`

should be:

`self.helper.layout.append(Column(Field('used',step='1'), css_class='form-group col-sm-4 mb-0 pb-0'))`